# NameError: name 's2gradefloat' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nameerror

I'm very new to python and i'm trying to create a GUI using tkinter that calculates the score you need on your final exam to get a certain grade. This is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x550+300+50")
root.title("")
backgroundcolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' %(0,0,0)
root.config(background= backgroundcolor)
#------------------Calculation----------------------#
def crscore():
    s2grade = float(s2gradef.get())
    dgrade = float(dgradef.get())
    rscore = (100*dgrade - (100 - 50)* s2grade ) / 50
    rscorelabel=Label(root,text="Required Test Score: %s" %rscore).place(x=250,y=370)
    return
#------------------Labels----------------------#
Label1=Label(root,
text='Final Exam Calclulator',
fg='white',
bg='black',
font= "a 17 bold").place(x=170,y=20)
Label3=Label(root,
text='Enter Current Semester 2 Grade',
fg='white',
bg='black',
font= "a 12 bold").place(x=100,y=100)

Label4=Label(root,
text='Enter Desired Final Grade',
fg='white',
bg='black',
font= "a 12 bold").place(x=100,y=165)
#------------------EntryBoxes----------------------#
s2grade = StringVar()
dgrade = StringVar()
s2grade = Entry(root,textvariable=s2grade).place(x=395,y=100)
dgrade = Entry(root,textvariable=dgrade).place(x=360,y=165)
#------------------Button----------------------#
button1=Button(root,text='Calculate Required Score',command=crscore).place(x=250,y=240)
root.mainloop()
```

But keep getting the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/FinalProject.py", line 10, in crscore
    s2grade = float(s2gradefloat.get())
NameError: name 's2gradefloat' is not defined
```

I realize i'm probably making many mistakes here. Can anyone help?

Comment: The code you showed does not even have a `s2gradefloat`. There is this line you have `s2grade = float(s2gradef.get())` inside the `crscore` where you are trying to access `s2gradef` as a dictionary, however you never declared it as such. So you might want to revise that.

Comment: @idjaw Okay i'm really new to programming do you think you could show me an example of how this could be done?

Comment: What is `s2gradef` supposed to be? You are trying to do something with it, so you must think that there is some kind of data in there that you expect. What should be in `s2gradef`?

Comment: looks like a typo, based on what he is trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your calculation function:

```
#------------------Calculation----------------------#

def crscore():
    s2grade = float(s2gradef.get())
    dgrade = float(dgradef.get())

s2gradefloat is not defined ---
```

basically, you are trying to get the value from your entry box I am asuming?

```
s2grade = Entry(root,textvariable=s2grade).place(x=395,y=100)
```

so you should be using `s2grade.get()`

but then again--- this will lead to another error - your variable is being referenced before assignment.

Another quick note:

you are re-using variable names locally, within your calculation function and outside of it, this is not a good practice

```
s2grade = StringVar()
dgrade = StringVar()
s2grade = Entry(root,textvariable=s2grade).place(x=395,y=100)
dgrade = Entry(root,textvariable=dgrade).place(x=360,y=165)
```

AND

```
def crscore():
    s2grade = float(s2gradef.get())
    dgrade = float(dgradef.get())
    rscore = (100*dgrade - (100 - 50)* s2grade ) / 50
    rscorelabel=Label(root,text="Required Test Score: %s" %rscore).place(x=250,y=370)
    return
```

Try and keep your variables unique, this will save you a lot of trouble.

For Ex:

```
#------------------Calculation----------------------#

def crscore():
    s2grad = float(s2grade.get())
    dgrad = float(dgrade.get())
    print(s2grad)
    print(dgrad)
    rscore = (100*dgrad - (100 - 50)* s2grad ) / 50
    rscorelabel=Label(root,text="Required Test Score: %s" %rscore).place(x=250,y=370)
    return
#------------------EntryBoxes----------------------#
s2grade = StringVar()
dgrade = StringVar()
Entry(root, textvariable=s2grade).place(x=395, y=100)
Entry(root, textvariable=dgrade).place(x=360, y=165)
#removed assigned variable names to the Entry widgets, as they are not being
#used " There's no point in assigning variables to 
#Entry(...).place(...) always returns None" as mentioned by @Brian Oakley
```

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to convert the numbers entered in the entry boxes to float so I can use it in this equation:      rscore = (100*dgrade - (100 - 50)* s2grade ) / 50

Comment: your conversion is good, just use a new variable name within your calculation function, instead of s2grade, idk, remove the 'e' and di s2grad=float(s2grade.get())

Comment: and replace your rscore variables for the local ones

Comment: If I change my variable names how will I convert the numbers entered in the entry boxes to floats?

Comment: view the revised answer, i added how to,, you use the get method on the text variable as you were doing, and convert to float, as you were doing but you assign to a new variable within your function and replace the variable name within "rscore"

Comment: Oh I see. That worked grate. Thanks I would have been screwed for my presentation without your help

Comment: There's no point in assigning to `s2grad` and `dgrad` in your example -- `Entry(...).place(...)` always returns `None`.

Comment: true, at the moment it is completely useless, I usually assign vars to widgets to later place, pack or grid rather than do it in one line or to later configure, left as is while messing around with the original code, modified answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out